# Switch to lower case across all entries in a mySQL tabel field

Tags: mysql, regex

Is there a way to force all entries in a particular field to be lower case across an entire table in one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET column = LOWER(column);
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a statement to force a column's alpha characters to be all lower cased.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = LOWER(MyColumn)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change all the data after the fact with an update:

```
update `your_table` set column=lower(column);
```

But as far as forcing this upon insert Im not sure.